# text replacement & seo

Tags: html, seo, semantics

I've been having a chat with a designer friend about text replacement and seo. I suspect I've got the wrong end of the stick, but I was under the impression that hiding content from users was bad practice. I'm aware that text is king and of separation of content & presentation. But to me this is a bit of a grey area. Is one considered best practice (with an seo slant)? I don't see one being more semantic than another, I suspect I will stand corrected.

```
<a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
```

with

```
background: image(pic.jpg);
text-indent: -9999px;
```

or

```
<a href="#">
   <img src="/delete.png" alt="delete" title="delete"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good SEO tips:

- provide content valuable *for users*
- always be honest

If you make `src`, `alt` and `title` the same, they do not add value at all.

I have always used position relative and negative result with good results. For icon buttons there is no difference. Do users consider image icons are more valuable than text links?

Also you should avoid `href="#"`, this is more important in this case than the rest.

BTW, If you make delete buttons crawlable by search engines, they will delete the content ;)

Comment: thanks. I was a bit lazy with the code in my question, it was more to illustrate my question...

Comment: Well, the quality of the answer heavily depends on quality of the question ;)

Comment: Is it best to tidy my question, or does that make the answer look odd

Comment: You are always free to update the question, but not to change it's meaning. Just mark in the question what have you updated. E.g. ##Edit: ...